# WebSocket(wss) Node Network issue

Tags: node.js, express, internet-explorer, websocket, wss

I build application on node-express using [WS](https://github.com/websockets/ws) library for websocket connection(wss).

everything works fine with Chrome but not in Explorer(11), and FireFox,
tried to play with ciphers and TLS version but still it can't connect
Also I could use only self-sign certificate.
I tried to build POC it still on the same level - I couldn't connect from Internet Explorer;
Here code example:

```html
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
let server
let serverOptions = {};
const WebSocket = require('ws');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ expected: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser);
const constants = require('constants');



let ciphers_new = ['TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384',
                    'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256',
                    'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256',
                    'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256',
                    'TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384',
                    'TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256',
                    'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384',
                    'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256',
                    'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384',
                    'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384',
                    'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256',
                     'aes128-gcm-sha256',
  'aes128-sha',
  'aes128-sha256',
  'aes256-gcm-sha384',
  'aes256-sha',
  'aes256-sha256',
  'dhe-psk-aes128-cbc-sha',
  'dhe-psk-aes128-cbc-sha256',
  'dhe-psk-aes128-gcm-sha256',
  'dhe-psk-aes256-cbc-sha',
  'dhe-psk-aes256-cbc-sha384',
  'dhe-psk-aes256-gcm-sha384',
  'dhe-psk-chacha20-poly1305',
  'dhe-rsa-aes128-gcm-sha256',
  'dhe-rsa-aes128-sha',
  'dhe-rsa-aes128-sha256',
  'dhe-rsa-aes256-gcm-sha384',
  'dhe-rsa-aes256-sha',
  'dhe-rsa-aes256-sha256',
  'dhe-rsa-chacha20-poly1305',
  'ecdhe-ecdsa-aes128-gcm-sha256',
  'ecdhe-ecdsa-aes128-sha',
  'ecdhe-ecdsa-aes128-sha256',
  'ecdhe-ecdsa-aes256-gcm-sha384',
  'ecdhe-ecdsa-aes256-sha',
  'ecdhe-ecdsa-aes256-sha384',
  'ecdhe-ecdsa-chacha20-poly1305',
  'ecdhe-psk-aes128-cbc-sha',
  'ecdhe-psk-aes128-cbc-sha256',
  'ecdhe-psk-aes256-cbc-sha',
  'ecdhe-psk-aes256-cbc-sha384',
  'ecdhe-psk-chacha20-poly1305',
  'ecdhe-rsa-aes128-gcm-sha256',
  'ecdhe-rsa-aes128-sha',
  'ecdhe-rsa-aes128-sha256',
  'ecdhe-rsa-aes256-gcm-sha384',
  'ecdhe-rsa-aes256-sha',
  'ecdhe-rsa-aes256-sha384',
  'ecdhe-rsa-chacha20-poly1305',
  'psk-aes128-cbc-sha',
  'psk-aes128-cbc-sha256',
  'psk-aes128-gcm-sha256',
  'psk-aes256-cbc-sha',
  'psk-aes256-cbc-sha384',
  'psk-aes256-gcm-sha384',
  'psk-chacha20-poly1305',
  'rsa-psk-aes128-cbc-sha',
  'rsa-psk-aes128-cbc-sha256',
  'rsa-psk-aes128-gcm-sha256',
  'rsa-psk-aes256-cbc-sha',
  'rsa-psk-aes256-cbc-sha384',
  'rsa-psk-aes256-gcm-sha384',
  'rsa-psk-chacha20-poly1305',
  'srp-aes-128-cbc-sha',
  'srp-aes-256-cbc-sha',
  'srp-rsa-aes-128-cbc-sha',
  'srp-rsa-aes-256-cbc-sha',
  'tls_aes_128_ccm_8_sha256',
  'tls_aes_128_ccm_sha256',
  'tls_aes_128_gcm_sha256',
  'tls_aes_256_gcm_sha384',
  'tls_chacha20_poly1305_sha256'
                ].join(':').toUpperCase();

console.log('here ',sslConfig.minimumTLSVersion)
    
serverOptions = {
    ca:fs.readFileSync(  './ca.pem'),
    key: fs.readFileSync( './key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./cert.pem'),
    honorCipherOrder: true,
    ciphers:ciphers_new,

  };


server = https.createServer(serverOptions, app);
    const handler = (req,res)=>{
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        res.end('Hello World\n');   
    }

server.addListener("request", handler);


const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server,
  handleProtocols: (protocols, client) => {
    return protocol;
} });

wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
  wsCount++;
  ws.send('give_cookie');

  ws.on('close', () => {
    wsCount--;
  })
})

wss.on('close',(e)=>{
    console.log('here we close')
})




server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is listening on port:${port}`);
});
```

Comment: Are you getting any error message in the browser console? I can see that you are using `=>` Arrow functions that is not supported in the IE browser. Are you transpiling the code? I try to check the library link and found this [note](https://imgur.com/a/pqJJsUw) in it. It also can be the possible reason why it is not working.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT this code I run on NodeJS on my server.

Comment: The above-posted code not giving any idea for the cause of the issue. I suggest you go to the `Network` tab in the developer tools. See whether it is showing any issue there. You can also try to use the Fiddler to check and find network related issue. Further, you can try to check this [code example](https://github.com/websockets/ws#how-to-detect-and-close-broken-connections) to find whether the connection is closed or broken.